# Need help clearing some types of UI

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

Im doing a paper for my college and I need some help finding some documentation or sources on some types of UI.

The types I need to research are WWWUI, MUI and VRUI. I know they are actually GUI but with added functionality of some sort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could possibly be better for the UI network

Comment: Going to guess that could mean, WWW (Web) UI, Mobile UI and Virtual Reality UI.

Comment: @vphilipnyc sorry for wrong tags didnt know what to put there